# Sort two files in Linux and find lines unique to each file

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, awk

I have 2 files.

File1 content looks like:

```
000000513609200,238/PLMN/000100
000000513609200,238/PLMN/000200
000050354428060,238/PLMN/000200
000050354428060,238/PLMN/000100
001212131415120,238/PLMN/000100
...
...
```

File2 contents:

```
000000513609200,238/PLMN/000100
000000513609200,238/PLMN/000200
000050354428060,238/PLMN/000200
000050354428060,238/PLMN/000100
001212131415120,238/PLMN/000100
...
...
```

File1 has close to 15000 records and file2 has close to 20000 records. I want to find the lines(records) present only in file1 or file2. I'm using the below:

```
comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file6
```

Is this a good option?

Also how exactly the sort works with these records ? How will it understand which column to take as primary key ?

Also can you suggest a simple awk script to do the comparison between file1 and file2 and forward the lines present either only in file1 or only in file2 to file7, so that I can compare the outputs. I want to make sure that my `comm` is yielding the same result.

Comment: `sort` with no options does a straight alphabetical sort. there are no fields, there are no columns. there's just strings to be compared. there's all kinds cli options you can specifiy if that's not good enough. `man sort` will explain some of it.

Comment: Is the fact your output file is `file6` (or `file7` from your text) rather than the more obvious `file3` relevant? I'm wondering if you're planning to compare more than 2 files and hoping to build on a solution that does only compare 2 files.

Comment: beware of the indentation in the output of `comm -3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do this without sorting:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {
   a[$0]
   next
}
{
   if ($0 in a)
      delete a[$0]
   else
      print
}
END {
   for (i in a)
      print i
}' file1 file2
```

Similarly using `grep` you can get the same using:

```
{ grep -vxFf file1 file2; grep -vxFf file2 file1; }
```

Comment: @dig_123, I suspect the awk answer may be faster than the comm answer since you don't have to do any sorting.

Comment: Just my opinion but: You seem to have picked up a very odd coding style lately - I've never seen code in any Algol-based language where a `{` on the same line following some other code means anything other than that you're introducing a block of code whose execution is in some way dependent on or at least associated with that preceding code block. Using `{` on the same line as a terminating `}` is particularly obfuscating in awk given it's `<condition> { <action> }` paradigm that newcomers already struggle to wrap their heads around.

Comment: Yes I think you have a fair point. These habits come from my Java coding all day where `else {` and `else if {` must be placed on the same line of closing `}` of preceding `if` block, otherwise it shows as an open issue in code analysis upon automated builds by `Sonarqube`

Answer (score 2):

This sorts with the -u (unique) flag and remove all duplicates in either files.

```
sort -u file1 file2 > file6
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/4231110

Comment: @JustinHoward Thank you. Yes, I could be more detailed. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, to simply sort the lines out based on any 'column', you can youse:

```
sort file1 file2 -t '/' -k 3 > file6
```

where *-t '/'* specifies the column delimiter, and *-k 3* specifies the column number based on this delimiter.

As for the second question, if you just want to compare the files you try out the *diff* command and see if it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are sorted (or can be sorted on the fly) you can also try join.  Since you don't have good test input I'm showing on a toy example

```
$ seq 5 > f1
$ seq 3 9 > f2
```

this gives the common records in both files, same as `comm -12 f1 f2`

```
$ join f1 f2  
3
4
5
```

this gives the unmatched records in both files, same as `comm -3 f1 f2 | sed 's/^\t//'`

```
$ join -v1 -v2 f1 f2
1
2
6
7
8
9
```